# Set a page to show only to registered users

Tags: 7, users

I have a website with two pages. The "home page" and a "notice page". The notice page should only be viewable to people who are logged in or people who have the role called "Basic User". I have created the role, but I cannot find how to set this notice page (basic page) to require log in.

Here is a similar question, but I think it is regarding drupal 6 and I know that a lot has changed when drupal 7 was released.

[Set a page to be only viewed by users who are logged in](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/10717/set-a-page-to-be-only-viewed-by-users-who-are-logged-in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a usable dev version of [Node Privacy by Role](http://drupal.org/project/node_privacy_byrole) for D7.

Alternatively, you could edit the templates for those pages to check a user's role before displaying the content. I can't really think of why you'd want to, but you could.

Comment: Is that really the only solution? I need to download a dev module to not show a page?

Comment: @EGHDK It comes in handy if you want more pages to be able to be viewed by authenticated users. Similar module http://drupal.org/project/nodeaccess

Comment: What if I only want one page or "content type" to be view-able by registered users?

Comment: By default drupal doesnt support it you need a module or a custom piece of code. You should be able to configure node by node.

Comment: Alright, I appreciate the feedback. Is `node_privacy_byrole` the "standard" for doing this?

Comment: No, it's not the only solution. You can also edit the template php or you can write your own custom module that contains a call to [hook_node_access()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_access/7). If you want to do it by content type you can edit the template for that whole content type.

Comment: It looks like I'm going to go ahead with a module to accomplish this for me. Why do these modules have bug reports. Shouldn't this be a simple task for a module to complete with no errors?

Comment: That is outside the scope of this question so I've opened a new question for it: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/39037/why-do-modules-have-bug-reports